# Allocating memory in an array of objects with out calling constructors?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to create a simple template arraylist class but when i do something like

```
T* typeArray = new T[10];
```

this creates 10 instances of the object, calling the constructor 10 times. How can i create an empty array were i can later place objects?

Comment: How would you "later place objects"? You'd have to use placement new, not simple assignment...

Comment: typeArray[index] = ...; this wouldnt work?

Comment: No. Calling the assignment operator requires a valid object on the left side.

Comment: i see so maybe i should create an array of pointers to objects?

Comment: Nope.  You should use a vector.

Comment: @JavaNewb: You would probably want `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` instances instead so that deallocating the thing causes delete to be called on the underlying bits automatically. Of course, it is likely that doing all those allocations would be far more expensive than just calling constructors.

Comment: Look into how the standard allocators do their magic. They allocate chunks of `char` and then use placement new to construct objects in the chunks. When doing this you need to be careful about alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
struct RawMem {
  alignas(T) unsigned char data[sizeof(T)];
  T& get_unsafe() { return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[0]); }
  T const& get_unsafe() const { return *reinterpret_cast<T const*>(&data[0]); }
  template<typename... Args>
  void Construct( Args&&... args ) {
    new (&data[0]) T( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
  void Destroy() {
    get_unsafe().~T();
  }
};

RawMem<std::string>* buff = new RawMem<std::string>[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  buff[i].Construct( "bob is your uncle" );
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  std::cout << buff[i].get_unsafe() << "\n";
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  buff[i].Destroy();
}
delete buff;
```

note that you are completely in charge of handling when the destructor is called, and when it isn't, with the above pattern.

I included helper `Construct` and `Destroy` functions so you don't have to mess around with placement `new` and the like yourself.  Similarly, `get_unsafe()` will let you get ahold of the `T&` instance when you want it.

The above uses C++11 `alignas`, because there is no way in C++03 to solve the problem.

Comment: @BillyONeal Horror at the lack of `unique_ptr`, but not at the array of manually constructed objects with no state that describes which is constructed and which not?

Comment: Yes. At least your example `RawMem` might accomplish something useful in some limited cases. There's no reason at all for having a manual `delete` in new code (unless writing an RAII class itself). Of course, some form of state should go into `RawMem` in order to ensure the contained `T` gets destroyed...

Answer (score 5):

It's not the preferred way of doing things in C++, but

```
T* my_array = (T*)malloc(10 * sizeof(T));
```

A solution more in line with standard C++ practice is

```
std::vector<T> my_vector;
my_vector.reserve(10);
```

Note, (as alluded to in comments) the solution with `reserve` differs in that without further action `my_vector[5]` is not valid whereas `my_array[5]` is.  You will subsequently need something like `my_vector.resize(10)` in order to index it, which will construct all 10 items.  You can construct them front-to-back by doing `push_back(T const&)` or `emplace_back(Args...&& args)`.  Only after constructed this way is `[]` indexing legal.  As a warning, `[]` indexing may work even when illegal, but it is undefined behavior.

Comment: `std::array` will cause constructor calls. +1 for the `vector` answer.

Comment: @BillyONeal Realized that, deleted.

Comment: ... and what exactly do you recommend the OP do with that `vector`?  Because there is a right and wrong answer just hanging there....

Comment: @Yakk I guess, hang on to it until he wants to put objects into it?  I've never been in a situation where I wanted to allocate first but delay construction to some later point, but maybe that's the situation OP is in somehow.  If "How can i create an empty array were i can later place objects?" is the question I don't see how either part of my answer is wrong.

Comment: The OP may be tempted to just do `my_vector[0]`, which is undefined behavior that will sometimes work, misleading the OP into thinking that they did nothing wrong.  :)  I just think you should mention what to do with your `my_vector` once you `reserve`!

Comment: @Yakk Ah I see what you mean.  I agree that's worth noting.